# How to get list of all hooks of current theme / plugin?

Tags: filters, hooks, actions

I want to get the list of all available hooks from active theme / from a specific plugin.

I was tried to get it from global variables `$wp_actions & $wp_filter` But, They are showing all registered hooks.

E.g.

```
global $wp_actions, $wp_filter;
echo '<pre>';
print_r($wp_filter);
```

E.g. If theme or plugin register the action in `after_setup_theme` then it'll list in `[after_setup_theme]` key from `global $wp_filter`.

I was tried one of the best plugin  `Simply Show Hooks`. But, It'll also, show all the registered hooks.

Is there any way to get the specific hooks from theme / plugin?

Comment: Don't you have a documentation of them, or in the theme/plugin website?

Comment: I've always just used the search feature in my IDE to scan the source code path for the "do_" function calls.

Comment: You could run the [WordPress PHPDoc parser](https://github.com/WordPress/phpdoc-parser) over the plugin's code (`wp parser parse .`), which will create a list of hooks (in addition to all functions/classes/etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 2016-09-25, there is no ideal solution.

The WP-Parser does the job, but you need to set up a special WP site to run it.
WooCommerce's `Hook-docs` is something much simpler, and can be easily tweaked.

I just wrote a long comment on the topic here:

https://github.com/ApiGen/ApiGen/issues/307#issuecomment-249349187

Answer (score 7):

As of 2019-10-16, the ideal solution would be: https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/

After installing the plugin, head over to your homepage (or wherever you need to get your list of hooks) and open Query Monitor from the admin bar.

Then, open **Hooks & Action**:
[image: Hooks & Actions tab in Query Monitor]

You will be able to view all the hooks in action, along with their component (e.g. plugin). You will also be able to filter by component.